# digest already in progress error in kibana 4

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, elastic-found

I have referred to these questions

[$digest already in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628191/digest-already-in-progress)
,
[Error: Digest already in Progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000664/error-digest-already-in-progress)
,
[AngularJS $digest already in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989239/angularjs-digest-already-in-progress)
but all these questions are related to development in java script. i'm not developing a website. details about kibana - Version: 4.3.1
Build: 9517. i'm just using kibana on elastic found and kibana 4 is throwing this below error.

```
Error: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest (https://5fe9b2fads8f7ad786fasdf78adfs03fc91.us-east-1.aws.found.io/bundles/commons.bundle.js:27160)
__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__</window.onerror@https://5fe9b2fb95f55abdc3b99e8d9e03fc91.us-east-1.aws.found.io/bundles/commons.bundle.js:64581:25
```

most of the answers to this error is related to editing the source code. i don't have control on the source code as kibana is on found.